# Estimating the number of integers relatively prime to $6$ between $1$ and some integer $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to understand the standard way to estimate the number of integers relatively prime to $6$ where we don't know which congruence class $x$ belongs to.

For a given $x$, if we know the congruence class, it is straight forward to determine the number of integers between $1$ and $x$ that are relatively prime to $6$.

If $x \equiv  0 \pmod 3$, the answer is $\frac{x}{3}$: i.e., between $1$ and $9$, there are $3$ that are relatively prime:  $\{ 1, 5, 7\}$

If $x \equiv 1 \pmod 6$, the answer is $\frac{x+2}{3}$: ie., between $1$ and $7$, there are $3$.

If $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, the answer is $\frac{x+1}{3}$

if $x \equiv 4 \pmod 6$, the answer is $\frac{x-1}{3}$

What be the standard answer for $x$ where we don't know the congruence class?

Would we say between $\frac{x-1}{3}$ and $\frac{x+2}{3}$?

What would be the right way for any $x$ to estimate the number of integers relatively prime to $6$?

Comment: An example estimate would be $\frac x3$ for large $x$, to highest order, with absolute error at most $\frac 23$. If you want a formula for the exact number there are ways of doing that.

Comment: @LarryFreeman $x/3$ ...............no?

Comment: Hi @Martin, that would be incorrect betwen $1$ and $2$.  The correct answer is $1$ but $\frac{2}{3}$ would not be correct.

Comment: Thanks @Mark.  What would be an example of a formula for the exact number?  How would that look like?

Comment: @LarryFreeman the sequence goes $1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6\dots$ - the *estimate* is $x/3$

Comment: @Martin, thanks for explaining.  Perhaps, I wasn't clear on my question.  I meant how would you in a mathematically precise way state the number of integers relatively prime to $6$ in a sequence such as:  $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,\dots,x\}$.  Wouldn't it you need to say $\frac{x}{3}$ with an absolute error of at most $\frac{2}{3}$ like Mark says?

Comment: @LarryFreeman well, `seq[nn_] := 
 With[{aa = (ConstantArray[1, #] & /@ 
      Table[3 + (-1)^n, {n, 0, Ceiling[nn/3]}])}, 
  Take[Flatten[aa*Range@Length@aa], nn]]` and then `seq[50]`gives sequence up to $50,$ as to defining it using correct mathematical notation, I will give it some thought...

Comment: One way of estimating the error is to use periodic functions like sixth roots of unity to the power $n$ - this will give an exact and algebraic expression. Other ways involve floor functions etc, which are simpler in some ways, but not in others.

Comment: Just assume that $x$ is a multiple of $6$. Then $x \over 3$ is a perfectly good estimate. As $x \to \infty$, the error percentage becomes infinitesimally small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of integers relatively prime to $6$ for each $x$ is given by the expression

$$\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}{6}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{6}\right\rfloor +1$$

which is clearly $\sim x/3.$

**Check:**

```
rp6[x_] := Floor[(x - 1)/6] + Floor[(x + 1)/6] + 1

{Length@Select[Range@#, GCD[#, 6] == 1 &] & /@ Range@40, 
rp6@# & /@ Range@40} // ListLinePlot
```

**Generalisation:**

The number of integers relatively prime to $n$ for each $x$ is $\sim x \cdot \phi(n)/n,$ where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.